# Django how to generate an automatic activation key for email activation link

Tags: django, email, key, activation

I would like to know how can I generate an automatic activation key to be concatinated to my email activation link 
That's the sent link : http://localhost:8001/sign_up/60/subsribe/14/confirmEmail
But for more security I want to send something like : http://localhost:8001/sign_up/60/subsribe/14/confirmEmail/{{ activation_key }}

```
mail = EmailMultiAlternatives("Confirmation d\'email pour finaliser votre inscripttion","pour finaliser votre inscription, veuillez consulter le lien ci-dessus ",from_email, to=[email])

mail.attach_alternative('http://localhost:8001/sign_up/' + str(id_account) + '/subscribe/' + str(id_sub) + '/confirmEmail',"text/html")

mail.send()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Signer class to achieve this. i.e.

```
from django.core.signing import Signer
signer = Signer()
signed_value = signer.sign(profile.user.email)#gives 'email@email.com:signed_things', extract signed_things'
key = ''.join(signed_value.split(':')[1:])
#send out key as part of url
```

You can then store the key with the user profile for instance. When the link is requested, you can do something like the following:

```
profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, key=key)
signer = Signer()
if signer.unsign('{0}:{1}'.format(profile.user.email, key)) == profile.user.email:
    profile.verified = True
```